# Generate solutions on esami

Tags: esami

I am using esami to make some multiple choice tests, but I can't generate the answers the way I want. I want the output file to have only the problems and at the end of all versions, the solutions are shown. I can only get both the answers at the MCQ and at the end of the test. I tried using options: "solutions,noquizsolutions", but yet it generates the test with solutions in MCQ. Any idea of how can I get only the solutions in a separate page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
        \usepackage{luatextra} 
        \usepackage{unicode-math}
        \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
        \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\else\ifxetex
        \usepackage{fixltx2e}
                \usepackage{fontspec}
                \usepackage{unicode-math}
                      \XeTeXinputencoding utf8
\else
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\fi\fi
\usepackage[shufflerandom,xyz,solutions,noquizsolutions,twocolumns]{esami}
\def\examname{Geometry Final}
\def\numcompiti{4}
\date{12/12/2017}
\def\Data{\longdate}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\testversioni
\pagestyle{esame}
\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers
\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}
\randomi=\seme
\permuta
\testa
\begin{test}[0]
\begin{questions}
\selectallproblems[random]{test11}
\end{questions}
\end{test}
\closevers
\newpage                                                                 
\setcounter{page}{1} 
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal example of your attempt?

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/991W0snd

Answer (score 1):

This feature has not been implemented in the package. The way that I can suggest (the one that we use when a separate file for solutions is required) is to create the solution file and to separate the page with the MCQ solution string. This page is placed at the end of the solutions file and we extract it using pdftk.

Comment: That won't work for me. I need the solutions separate from the questions and yet keep the questions blank, so I can give copies to the students. If I separe the solutions from one batch of compilation,  when I compile the blank file again, the questions will be scrambled so the solutions won't be correct anymore :(

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the problem. The text of the exam and the solution of the same exam are compiled in different and separate files: in the doc folder of the package, you can find a `master.tex` (with the `nosolutions` option, for the text of the exam) and a `master-sol.tex` (with the `solutions` option, which prints the text of the exercises and the solutions). Apart from the `solutions`/`nosolutions` options, if the two files are identical, they give always the same output. In particular, you must check if the random seed is the same in both files to have the same output.

Comment: Are you sure that they will output the same set of questions in the same order even if I compile them one after the other?

Comment: Yes, I am completely sure. We compile both the text and the solutions many, many times to correct errors and we always obtain the same output in the two files. You must only be sure that the random seed is defined the same way both in the text and in the solutions and that it does not depend on time. For what I see in your code, the seed is correctly defined, so you should not have any problems.

Comment: Interesting... I thought the random seed would generate different outputs every time I compile the code. Thanks. One more thing. I am noticing that some of the versions of the test come up with wrong page numbers, like page 1 then page 1 again and then page 2, while the other versions have correct page numbers. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem with the code you posted. Can you please post (or send me via e-mail, you can find it in the package documentation) a MWE of a file that has this problem?

Comment: Here:https://pastebin.com/679A6hW8

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the floats and \thepage option. Some of the questions have floats and I heard that \thepage won't work properly.

Comment: With the example that you posted I do not have the problem you reported. Can you please send or link the pdf file with the problem?

Comment: I think you need to load the questions as well. Some of them have pictures, and I suspect those are the culprits. Have a look at some of them: https://pastebin.com/mXC6YiHV

Comment: Without the pictures it is impossible to try and see what's going wrong. I use lots of pictures in my exams, both generated by pstricks or tikz during the compilation or inserted via `\includegraphics`. I never had such a problem. If you can send a _complete_ example maybe we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: I tried messing around with the code that handles pictures and definitively it has something to do with it. I now get pages printed as 1,1,2,3 and 4, instead of 1,2,3,4,5. So close... I can't send a complete example, but can you show me how did you add pics to multiple choice questions?

Comment: If you need more help, please write to my e-mail (you find it in the package documentation). It does not comply to stackexchange standards to have "personal" conversations in a post.